# TwitterアプリのようなUIについて

Tags: android

現在、TwitterのタイムラインのようなUIを持つアプリを開発しておりまして、実装方法に悩んでおります。

あるユーザを選択した時に、ヘッダー部分にユーザのアイコンや自己紹介文を表示し、その下には、当該ユーザのコメントリストが並ぶというありきたりのUIとなります。また、ヘッダ部分は位置が固定ではなく、コメントリストのスクロールと共に上部へスライドしていくというものになります。

そこで、単にListViewを用いて一度実装を行いました。

ArrayAdapterのgetViewをオーバーライドして、positionが0、つまりヘッダ部分のみ異なるレイアウトファイルを適用し、それ以外のpositionについては、コメントを表示するためのレイアウトファイルを適用して、当初予定していたUIは実装が行えました。

その後、これを拡張することになり、ヘッダ部分内にタブ切り替えのようなボタンを配置し、選択されたボタンにより、下位のリスト内容をごっそり切り替えるということになりました。

デフォルトでは、コメントリストなのですが、切り替えボタンを押すと、内容もレイアウトも全く異なるものを表示することになります。（例えば、当該ユーザがフォローしている他ユーザの一覧等。リスト形式であることには変わりません）

ヘッダ部分の内容は全く変更せず（ただし、選択されたボタンはハイライト化）、positionが1以降のリストを、内容もレイアウトも異なるものに切り替えるために、皆さんならどのように実装されるかご意見をお聞かせ願えないでしょうか。

要件として、ヘッダー部のスクロール位置の変更はしないという制限があります。 （例えばちょっとだけスクロールしていて、一部が隠れている状態での切替時）

私が今考えているのは、getViewの中で、現在positionが0かそれ以外でレイアウトファイルを切り替えるだけでなく、さらにどの切替ボタンが選択されているかで、適用するレイアウトファイルを増やすというものなのですが、何か強引な感じがして・・・

もっとスマートな方法がございましたら、ご教示いただきたく。 （違うアクティビティなり、フラグメントに切り替えて、前画面と同じ位置にスクロールさせる等？）

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Androidですと、Action BarにTabを追加するのが一般です。Tab切替時に表示するFragmentを切り替えます。その上で、各フラグメント上に共通で表示したい物（ユーザ情報等）を部品化する設計にするのがよろしいかと思います。

参考サイト
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs
http://android.keicode.com/basics/actionbar-tab.php
http://qiita.com/mackiso/items/bb3cacac6c0bfb9eb3df

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ただ、ヘッダ部は複数の子viewを配置しなければならなく、かつタブのデザインも、それら子viewの下に配置し、角丸のボタンにしなくてはならず・・・
そのようなカスタマイズができるのでしょうか

Comment: ヘッダ部分はAction BarやTabに含まれないので、如何様にも作れます。私の提案はタブ部分の実装で、Androidのデザインガイドに沿ったユーザーインターフェースで作成する方法です。「TwitterアプリのようなUI」「もっとスマートな...」ということでしたので、提案しました。どうしてもタブボタンをヘッダ部に含んで、リストと一緒にスクロールするような独自のUIにする必要があるのであれば、Action Bar + Tabではできません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
返事が遅くなりました。
その後、もう少しListViewについて調査してみたところ、そもそもヘッダやフッタを追加するaddHeaderView()やaddFooterView()なるドンピシャなメソッドが存在していたのですね・・・
こちらを利用して書き換えてみます。
http://www.binzume.net/diary/2011-03-19:A3
もう、まさにここでダメな例として挙げられている方法で実装しておりました。

Answer (score 1):

ヘッダー（タブ）はリストに含めないほうがよいと思います。

[Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)の`CoordinatorLayout`は使えませんかね？

参考：https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
確かにヘッダをリストに含めるのはどうかと思ってまして。
お教えいただいたページで、ヘッダ部に複数の子viewが配置できるのか模索してみます